# Conditional Formatting to ingore hidden rows

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, google-sheets-formula

I have the following problem. I use conditional formatting commands such as to mark the lowest two numeric values in a column. `=OR(AC4=MIN(SORTN($AC$4:$AC$42;2;2;1;1));AC4=MAX(SORTN($AC$4:$AC$42;2;2;1;1)))`

Sometimes, however I somtimes have to hide certain rows. The formatting also marks those values (if they are the lowest). Can I somehow edit my formatting command so that it ignores all hidden cells, even if they are within the range of the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Suggestion: use `SUBTOTAL` to identify and filter hidden rows

Try using this formula in your conditional formatting:

EDIT: I've updated the formula based on your last comment

```
=OR(AC4 = MIN(SORTN(
  FILTER($AC$4:$AC$42,
    MAP($AC$4:$AC$42, LAMBDA(row, SUBTOTAL(103, row))) = 1), 2, 2, 1, 1));
AC4 = MAX(SORTN(
  FILTER($AC$4:$AC$42,
    MAP($AC$4:$AC$42, LAMBDA(row, SUBTOTAL(103, row))) = 1), 2, 2, 1, 1)))
```

For additional context:

- `MAP($AC$4:$AC$42, LAMBDA(row, SUBTOTAL(103, row))` creates a virtual column to identify the hidden rows. This returns a value of `1` for each row if it is visible and `0` if the row is hidden.
- The `FILTER()` function then filters out the range `AC:AC42` and only returns the visible rows, i.e. rows wherein the `MAP()` function above returned a value of `1`
- `SMALL()` looks up the nth smallest value in the dataset returned by the `FILTER()` function. The formula above looks for both the smallest and the 2nd smallest value in the filtered values of the range `AC4:AC42`

### References:

- [SUBTOTAL()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093649)
- [LAMBDA()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718)
- [MAP()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568985)
- [FILTER()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197)
- [SMALL()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094050)

Comment: Hi @ica ica, was the answer above able to address your issue?

Comment: hi @duueyn, thanks for the help I appreciate it! However I get "invalid formular" upon trying to apply it in the custom formular formatting rules.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was not getting any errors when testing the formula on different sheets. The "invalid formula" error normally shows up if the formula is incomplete. For example, there might be a missing parenthesis at the end. Please make sure to copy the entire formula. In addition, try applying the conditional formatting specifically to the range`AC4:AC42`. Let me know if you are still encountering an error.

Comment: hi @duueyn. Sadly even with your edited formular I still encounter "invalid formular"

Comment: Hi @ica ica, I'm afraid I can't replicate the error you're getting, even on other Google accounts. One reason I can think of is that the formula was automatically getting modified when you copy or paste it. Would you be able to respond with the formula that's throwing an error just to confirm if it is the same one as on the answer above? And if possible, can you confirm if you can replicate the error on other Google Sheets?

Comment: hi @duueyn, thanks for all your help! The error was due to the regionale in the sheet using ; instead of ,. I can paste the formular now, but it doesn't mark any values. I have tried it in other columns/sheets and it works fine. Im kinda confused on why it doesn't work in the specific columns I need it to work in...

Comment: Hi @ica ica, glad to hear you got the formula to work on other sheets/columns. As for why it is not working on your specific column, it's possible that conditional formatting was not applying to the correct range. The formula is only meant to check the values on the range `AC4:AC42`. You may need to adjust the range in the conditional formatting or in the formula if the data is on a different range.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I figured out it didnt work in that specific column, bc I had a formular in a cell that spits out #VALUE until it is used, then it returns a numeric value and works as expected. In my other columns, it works well. However, would it be possible to change the formular that it also marks the lowest numeric value if there is just one ? At the moment there has to be at least two values to make the whole formatting start. It would be great if the first value is marked no matter what it is, and then from then on adding one, both are marked since its the 2 lowest.

Comment: when there's 3 it then starts to look for the 2 lowest etc. Also when I have say "12" as value twice and 13 once, it marks those 2 12's. It would be great if it could also include the 13, basically marking the two lowest values regardless on how often they are in the column, not the two lowest numbers itself. I don't know if this makes sense to you.  My inital formular in my question was able to, do that, as well as mark the first price. I'm guessing this has to do with using MIN and MAX instead of SMALL? Would it be possible to edit the formular in a way to be able to do all that?

Comment: Hi, I've updated the formula to fit your requirements. Let me know if it works for you.